# Rails 3 way of doing skip_before_filter, :only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, before-filter

In rails 2.8 we can write skip_before_filter like this

```
skip_before_filter :require_login, :only => [:create,:new,:accept]
```

which means, i wanted to apply the filter  `require_login` only to these actions `[:create,:new,:accept]`, and skip the filter for others.

But it seems, this way is [deprecated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/skip_before_filter#1083-deprecated-moved) in rails 3. And new [skip_filter](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/skip_filter) is added. i have tried  this

```
 skip_filter :require_login, :only => [:create,:new,:accept]
```

but its not working, so how can i do this in rails 3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `skip_before_filter` has not been deprecated, [see source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb).
- You're using it as expected.

So how did you deduce it's not working properly?

Comment: :D I often face the same kind of situations ;)

Answer (score 16):

That is an incorrect use of `skip_before_filter`.

In order to apply the filter `require_login` exclusively to the actions `[:create,:new,:accept]`, and skip the filter for others, you must first apply the filter:

```
before_filter :require_login
```

Then you must tell rails to skip this filter **except** for actions "create, new and accept".

```
skip_before_filter :require_login, :except => [:create,:new,:accept]
```

you can also use `skip_filter`, which allows you to include `before_filter`, `after_filter`, and `around_filter` filters:

```
skip_filter :require_login, :except => [:create,:new,:accept]
```

Reference: [Rails 3.2 guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/action_controller_overview.html#filters)

In Rails 4.0, the equivalent methods are :before_action, and :skip_before_action.

Reference: [Rails 4.0 guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)